# how to replace document.write with another option

Tags: javascript

hi i want to alter this code to use anything but not document.write() because its not accepted on many browsers but iam not expert with js so what can i do to make this code work with anything except
here is the initial code

```
 <script src=https://courses.nooor.me/forms/2148061262/embed.js></script>
```

and here is the src code :

```
(function() {
  // write the form
  document.write("<link href=\'//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700\' rel=\'stylesheet\' type=\'text/css\'>\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all\" href=\"https://kajabi-app-assets.kajabi-cdn.com/assets/form_embed-70ab594381937fc46cadbbaab29c12b724dc077086662f2bbd495c08e46bb08d.css\" />\n<script src=\"https://kajabi-app-assets.kajabi-cdn.com/assets/form_embed-fd7a5360fe56f0a332f934492d89f18c2202d65871804504adca6fd4b6e78ceb.js\"><\/script>\n\n<div id=\"kajabi-form\" class=\"kajabi-form--inline\">\n  <form data-parsley-validate=\"true\" data-kjb-disable-on-submit=\"true\" action=\"https://courses.nooor.me/forms/2148061262/form_submissions\" accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"utf8\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"&#x2713;\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"authenticity_token\" value=\"6DILpEdVQHFVJ0kV0u1hpzvxfzOZr3jElsbnhd7RHMsl6oWuWuppgglToe3+bNy4fD/GXE+L5Wt3JC/rO0IvTA==\" />\n      <style id=\"form-embed-style\" type=\"text/css\">\n\n  <\/style>\n\n\n<div class=\"kajabi-form__content\">\n  <div class=\"kajabi-form__title\">JOIN THE NEWSLETTER<\/div>\n  <div class=\"kajabi-form__subtitle\">\n    <p style=\"text-align: center;\">Subscribe to get our latest content by email.<\/p>\n  <\/div>\n  <fieldset>\n      <div class=\"text-field kajabi-form__form-item\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"form_submission[name]\" id=\"form_submission_name\" value=\"\" required=\"required\" placeholder=\"Name\" /><\/div>\n      <div class=\"email-field kajabi-form__form-item\"><input required=\"required\" placeholder=\"Email\" data-parsley-remote=\"true\" data-parsley-remote-validator=\"kjb_email_validator\" type=\"email\" name=\"form_submission[email]\" id=\"form_submission_email\" /><\/div>\n      <div class=\"phone-field kajabi-form__form-item\"><input placeholder=\"WhatsApp Number\" type=\"tel\" name=\"form_submission[phone_number]\" id=\"form_submission_phone_number\" /><\/div>\n      <button class=\"kajabi-form__btn kajabi-form__btn--block-mobile\" type=\"submit\">Subscribe<\/button>\n  <\/fieldset>\n<\/div>\n\n<\/form><\/div>\n");
})();
```

i want to add an embedded form but they use doucment.write and its not working on the site i try to
embed to i tried console.log and it didn't work and i tried innerhtml but i dont think i could write the syntax right  and i don't know what to do
here is the code which i try to embed this form at :

```
<script data-b24-form="inline/51/0jcr3u" data-skip-moving="true">



  main();

  function main() {

    var Bucket_form = document.getElementsByClassName('leadCaptureForm')[0];
    if (typeof (Bucket_form) == 'undefined' || Bucket_form == null) {
      window.setTimeout(window.main, 1000);
      return false;
    }

(function(w,d,u){
var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=true;s.src=u+'?'+(Date.now()/180000|0);
var h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);
})(window,document,'https://cdn.bitrix24.com/b14743047/crm/form/loader_51.js');


    window.sub();
  }

  function sub() {

    var Bitrix_form = document.getElementsByClassName("b24-form")[0];

    if (typeof (Bitrix_form) == 'undefined' || Bitrix_form == null) {
      window.setTimeout(window.sub, 1000);
      return false;
    }

    var Bucket_form_container = document.getElementsByClassName("css-1usce2m")[0];
    Bucket_form_container.style.opacity = "0";
    Bucket_form_container.style.zIndex = "0";
    Bucket_form_container.style.marginTop = "200px";
    document.getElementsByClassName("css-ij0ne0")[0].remove();

    var form = document.querySelector(".b24-form-content > form");
    var name = document.querySelector(".b24-form-control-container > input[name='name']");
    var email = document.querySelector(".b24-form-control-container > input[name='email']");
var code= document.querySelectorAll('.b24-form-control-container > input[type="string"]')[1];
var phone =  document.querySelector(".b24-form-control-container > input[name='phone']");
    var resend_button = document.querySelector(".b24-form-error > .b24-form-state-inner > button");
    var error_status = document.querySelector(".b24-form-error");
    var Bucket_form = document.querySelector("#if94 > form");
    var Bucket_button = document.querySelector("#i47ntc > button");
    var Bucket_name = document.querySelector("#irmx4");
    var Bucket_email = document.querySelector("#ivo49");
    var Bucket_phone = document.querySelector("#igplg");
    var Bucket_code = document.querySelector("#i18e6");

    name.addEventListener("input", function nameChange() {
      Bucket_name.value = this.value;
     
    });
    email.addEventListener("input", function emailChange() {
      Bucket_email.value = this.value;
     
    });
 code.addEventListener("input", function emailChange() {
      Bucket_code.value = this.value;
     
    });
      phone.addEventListener("focus", function phoneFocus() {
      if (code.value.trim() == "") {
        code.click();
        return false;
      }
      if (this.value.trim() == "") {
        this.value = code.value;
      }
    });
 phone.addEventListener("keyup", function phoneInput() {
      var phoneValue = this.value;
      phoneValue = phoneValue.replaceAll("(", "");
      phoneValue = phoneValue.replaceAll(")", "");
      phoneValue = phoneValue.replaceAll("-", "");
      phoneValue = phoneValue.replaceAll(" ", "");
      this.value = phoneValue;
      Bucket_phone.value = phoneValue;
    
    });
    form.addEventListener("submit", function formSubmit() {
      if (name.value.trim() != "" && email.value.trim() != "") {
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
          resend_button.click();
          resend_button.disabled = true;
          resend_button.remove();
          error_status.remove();
        }
        Bucket_button.click();
    
      }
    });
  }
</script>

<style>
  .b24-form {
    margin-top: 50px !important;
  }
  .leadCaptureForm, .b24-form-success {
    opacity: 0 !important;
  }
 
</style>
```

and here is the page that i try to embed the code in it :
https://go2.bucketforms.com/sf/4b2a4fae

Comment: I don’t see why this needs any JavaScript at all. What does the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/write) reveal?

Comment: on what browser does `document.write` not work? I've not seen it fail anywhere...

Comment: i get this error when i use this function :
A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored" in the error console.

Comment: My guess the line is included in a file that's loaded as a module or loaded deferred.

Comment: it's because i use bucket io and it's XHTML which is banning using document.write

Comment: That error message is not saying that `document.write` is banned. It just protects you from clearing the whole document, which cannot be your purpose.

Comment: yes it's not my purpose so how can i embed this code into the second one and make it works?

Comment: How do the two code blocks relate?

Comment: i want to add the first one to the second code

Comment: In this case, have you thought about using the HTML dynamically through the `createElement()` method?

Comment: if i did i will write some integrations code to write one form once and it will write the input in 2 other forms

Comment: i dont know how to edit the code to use createElement()

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Just do *innerHTML*, *innerText*, or *createElement*

Sample:

```
function() {
  // write the form
  document.getElementById("HTMLtag.id").innerHTML = `
  <div>
   <p>You can do this alternative for document.write().</p>
  </div>
`
}
```

Comment: excuse my ignorance where can i type this : "<link href=\'//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700\' rel=\'stylesheet\' type=\'text/css\'>\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all\" href=\"https://kajabi-app-assets.kajabi-cdn.com/assets/form_embed-70ab594381937fc46cadbbaab29c12b724dc077086662f2bbd495c08e46bb08d.css\" />\n<script src=\"https://kajabi-app-assets.kajabi-cdn.com/assets/form_embed-fd7a5360fe56f0a332f934492d89f18c2202d65871804504adca6fd4b6e78ceb.js\"><\/script>\n\n ...........

Comment: and where to add this code inside the second block

Comment: If you are making form in *"html"*  you can use it in your html tag ex:```<p id="output"></p>```. Better make an playground or working sample of your project for easy debugging the problem.